# Some examples of iterative functions to find join occurence in columns' dataset

Tags: r, loops, duplicates, dataset, iteration

I have a very complex dataset where I am struggling to find with R, the joint occurrence through four main columns in their values' rows. To explain this better, I am providing the following example with the `airquality` dataset, where just for simplicity purposes, I will show two main examples:

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
libra
library(data.table)
install.packages('hablar')
library(hablar)

#1st example 
airquality %>% 
  select(Wind, Temp) %>% 
  find_duplicates(Wind, Temp)

#2nd example 
airquality %>% 
  select(Wind, Month) %>% 
  find_duplicates(Wind, Month)
```

And so on. Just to avoid writing separate chunks of code to iterate the same operation for further columns, could you please suggest another iterative mode for the same results (**for loops, map() functions, apply() functions)**. Could you please show as follows some examples?

Just to clarify the **output** I am looking for seems more a less to a table such as the one provided below:

```
# A tibble: 31 x 2
    Wind  Temp
   <dbl> <int>
 1   6.9    74
 2  11.5    68
 3  14.9    81
 4   7.4    76
 5   8      82
 6  11.5    79
 7  14.9    77
 8  10.3    76
 9   6.3    77
10  14.9    77
# ... with 21 more rows
```

But I would like to iterate the same result for many columns of interest

**P.s.** I know that instead of using `function 'find_duplicates from the package ('hablar')` there are different. So you have any further suggestions, feel free to implement this in your solution. It will be very appreciated.

Thank you so much for paying attention

Comment: What's your desired output? I don't want to install `hablar`, but maybe you can try `combn(airquality, 2, FUN = function(x) cbind(x, Dup = duplicated(x)) ,simplify = FALSE)`.

Comment: Thanks for your example. This is the kind of what I am looking for. However, since my dataset has many columns I am trying to find a solution all-in-one round, just on that selected columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will return you a `list` of your expected `data.frame`s

```
mycolumns= c("Wind", "Month", "Ozone", "Solar.R")

columnpairs <- as.data.frame(combn(mycolumns, 2))

result <- lapply(columnpairs, function(x) 
  airquality %>% 
    select(Wind, Temp) %>% 
    find_duplicates(Wind, Temp)
  )
```

Regular `dplyr` runs it 37% faster:

```
result_dplyr <- lapply(columnpairs, function(x) {
  airquality %>% 
    select(all_of(x)) %>% 
    group_by(across(all_of(x))) %>% filter(n() > 1)
}
)
result_dplyr
$V1
# A tibble: 105 x 2
# Groups:   Wind, Month [40]
    Wind Month
   <dbl> <int>
 1   7.4     5
 2   8       5
 3  11.5     5
 4  14.9     5
 5   8.6     5
 6   8.6     5
 7   9.7     5
 8  11.5     5
 9  12       5
10  11.5     5
# ... with 95 more rows

$V2
# A tibble: 31 x 2
```

Benchmarking:

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+   hablar = lapply(columnpairs, function(x) airquality %>% select(Wind, Temp) %>% find_duplicates(Wind, Temp)),
+   dplyr= lapply(columnpairs, function(x) {airquality %>% select(all_of(x)) %>% group_by(across(all_of(x))) %>% filter(n() > 1) })
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 hablar 123.6340 127.66205 132.8422 130.6805 133.7052 210.2259   100
  dplyr  75.8762  81.19705  82.5891  82.2986  83.6467  98.0426   100
```