# How to transfer a column from a dataset sharing the same one with another one

Tags: r, dplyr, dataset, iteration

I have two versions of datasets sharing the same columns (more or less). Let's take as an example

```
db = airquality
db1 = airquality[,-c(6)]
db1$Ozone[db1$Ozone < 30] <- 24
db1$Month[db1$Month == 5] <- 24

db
db1
```

If I would like to transfer two columns 'Ozone' and 'Wind' from the dataset 'db1' to the 'db' dataset by writing a code using the pipe operator %>% or another iterative method to achieve this result, which code you may possibly suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You csn do:

```r
library(dplyr)

db1 %>% 
  select(Ozone, Wind) %>% 
  bind_cols(db)
```

Note that in this example, since some column names will be duplicated in the final result, `dplyr` will automatically rename the duplicates by appending numbers to the end of the column names.

Comment: `db %>% 
  bind_cols(Ozone_db1 = db1$Ozone, Wind_db1 = db1$Wind)` maybe better?

Comment: @TarJae yes, I'd probably use something like that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73246436/some-examples-of-iterative-thanks. Here I have published a kind of similar question functions-to-find-join-occurence-in-columns-dataset?noredirect=1#comment129358236_73246436 . Just feel to provide your examples. It is always appreaciated and instructive.

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

```
cbind(db, db1[,c(1,3)])
```

```
   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day Ozone Wind
1      41     190  7.4   67     5   1    41  7.4
2      36     118  8.0   72     5   2    36  8.0
3      12     149 12.6   74     5   3    24 12.6
4      18     313 11.5   62     5   4    24 11.5
5      NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5    NA 14.3
6      28      NA 14.9   66     5   6    24 14.9
7      23     299  8.6   65     5   7    24  8.6
8      19      99 13.8   59     5   8    24 13.8
9       8      19 20.1   61     5   9    24 20.1
10     NA     194  8.6   69     5  10    NA  8.6
11      7      NA  6.9   74     5  11    24  6.9
12     16     256  9.7   69     5  12    24  9.7
.
.
.
```